# Odoo 13.0 website_sale: convert price from company currency to public pricelist

Tags: web, python-3.7, currency, odoo-12, odoo-13

In Odoo 12 we had a function to get current website pricelist and company currency id, and then convert product price from company currency id to website currency id.

This function:  `_get_compute_currency()`

But in Odoo 13, Odoo team removed it.

I am asking, if we use website sale in multi-currencies and my company currency is neither USD nor EUR, what option for me to convert product from my company currency to pricelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in function `_get_combination_info()` has a block to do this job

```
        if pricelist and pricelist.currency_id != product_template.currency_id:
            list_price = product_template.currency_id._convert(
                list_price, pricelist.currency_id, product_template._get_current_company(pricelist=pricelist),
                fields.Date.today()
            )
```